# Porqué me estan llegando prospectos vacíos? Formulario HTML con Re Captcha V3 de Google y PHP

Tags: php, html

He realizado un sitio web e Wordpress con un formulario insertado que se le ha añadido el Recaptcha V3 de Google, estos datos se envía a Salesforce para el seguimiento de los prospectos y posteriormente sean contactados.
De un tiempo para acá comenzaron a llegar prospectos vacíos al Salesforce, por lo que implementamos un Recapcha de Google para evitar que sigan llegando prospectos vacíos, posteriormente añadimos al código PHP una condicional para comprobar que los campos no se fueran vacíos. el formulario tiene este código:

```
<form action="recibeesp.php" method="POST">


<label for="first_name">Nombre(s):</label><input id="first_name" maxlength="100" name="first_name" size="30" type="text" required> <br> 
<label for="last_name">Apellidos:</label><input id="last_name" maxlength="100" name="last_name" size="30" type="text" required> <br>
<label for="email">Correo Electrónico:</label><input type="Email" maxlength="100" name="email" size="20" type="email" required><br>
<label for="mobile">Móvil:</label><input  id="mobile" maxlength="40" name="mobile" size="13" type="text" required><br>

   
<label for="country_code">País:</label><select  id="country_code" name="country_code" required="required">
<option value="MX">México</option>
<option value="AF">Afganistán</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DE">Alemania</option>
<option value="AD">Andorra</option>
<option value="AO">Angola</option>

</select><br>
 
    <label for="state">Estado:</label><input  id="00No000000BVqR6" maxlength="20" name="00No000000BVqR6" size="20" type="text" /><br>

        Estado Civil:
        <select  id="00N1N00000FBnr7" name="00N1N00000FBnr7" title="Estado Civil" required>
            <option value="">--Ninguno--</option>
            <option value="Soltero">Soltero</option>
            <option value="Soltera">Soltera</option>
            <option value="Casado">Casado</option>
            <option value="Casada">Casada</option>
            <option value="Viudo">Viudo</option>
            <option value="Viuda">Viuda</option>
            <option value="Divorciado">Divorciado</option>
            <option value="Soltero viajando con hijos">Soltero viajando con hijos</option>
            <option value="Soltera viajando con hijos">Soltera viajando con hijos</option>
            <option value="Casado viajando sin cónyuge">Casado viajando sin cónyuge</option>
            <option value="Unión Libre">Unión Libre</option>
        </select><br>
            Edad:
        <select  id="00N1N00000FBnrC" name="00N1N00000FBnrC" title="Edad" required>
            <option value="">--Ninguno--</option>
            <option value="20-25">20-25</option>
            <option value="26-29">26-29</option>
            <option value="30-35">30-35</option>
            <option value="36-40">36-40</option>
            <option value="41-45">41-45</option>
            <option value="46-50">46-50</option>
            <option value="51-60">51-60</option>
            <option value="60+">60+</option>
            
        
       </select><br>

                        <div class="w-full block md:inline-block md:w-1/2 md:pr-1">
                            <label>Hora de Contacto:</label>
                            <input id="description" 
                                class="appearance-none block w-full text-gray-700 border border-gray-700 rounded-lg py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-300"
                                type="time"
                                name="description">
                            <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic hidden">
                        </div>
   </div>
    
<br>

    
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"> <br>

</form>
```

Esto en conjunto al PHP que envía los datos a Salesforce:

```
<?php

$origTime   = $_POST['description'];
$newTime    = date("H:i", strtotime($origTime)).":00";
$data       = array(
  //Obligatorios para candidatos
  'url'             => 'https://trendingtravel.club/eng/',
  'oid'             => '00000000',//id de la compania
  'lead_source'     => 'VVVVVV',
  'company'         => 'XXXXXXX',
  'recordType'      => '0121N000001QB3C', //** MDC PROSPECTO ESTANDAR *** HECHO
  '00No000000BV8VY' => 'Espa単ol',  //Languaje
  '00N1N00000PF7nQ' => 'Espa単ol',  //idioma
  '00N1N00000FBk2j' => 'Otros', //
  '00No000000CN9w0' =>'Directo', //Tipo de cliente
  //En orden del formulario----------------------------------
  'first_name'      => $_POST['first_name'],
  'last_name'       => $_POST['last_name'],
  'email'           => $_POST['email'],
  'mobile'          => $_POST['mobile'], // QUE SOLO INGRESEN NUMEROS SIN ESPACIOS
 'country_code'     => $_POST['country_code'], //Pais countrycode
 '00No000000BVqR6'  => $_POST['00No000000BVqR6'], //Edo o Provincia Fiscal
'00N1N00000FBnr7'   => 'Casado', //$_POST['00N1N00000FBnr7'], //Estado Civil del lead
'00N1N00000FBnrC'   => $_POST['00N1N00000FBnrC'],//edad
'description'       => "El Prospecto desea ser contactado en el siguiente horario: ".$newTime //Campo descripcion + horario visita

);

/*
echo '<pre> data ';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre> ';
*/
$url ='https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8';
$ch = curl_init($url); //var global

$POSTString = http_build_query($data);//asigna valores del array
/*
echo '<pre> data ';
print_r($POSTString);
echo '</pre> ';
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);//muestra en pantalla

$response = curl_exec($ch);
// echo $response;
//obtiene respuesta de ch
curl_close($ch); //cierre conexion
var_dump($data);//manda valores de array

if($POSTString){
    header('Location: https://trendingtravel.club/gracias/');
}

?>
```

Pero continuamos recibiendo prospectos vacíos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que pueda asesorarme el porqué siguen llegando vacíos?

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obiamente hay alguien que se esta pasando las validaciones del navegador haciendo la peticion directa, vuelve a validar de lado del servidor en sales force antes de la peticion curl_init. a mi gusta dar un codigo de error pero con un simple return basta.

```
if(empty($_POST['first_name']) || empty($_POST['last_name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['mobile']) || empty($_POST['country_code']) || empty($_POST['00No000000BVqR6']) || empty($_POST['00N1N00000FBnr7']) || empty($_POST['00N1N00000FBnrC']))
{
    http_response_code(401);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, quedó de la siguiente forma, espero haberlo hecho bien:

/*
echo '<pre> data ';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre> ';
*/

if(empty($_POST['first_name']) || empty($_POST['last_name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['mobile']) || empty($_POST['country_code']) || empty($_POST['00No000000BVqR6']) || empty($_POST['00N1N00000FBnr7']) || empty($_POST['00N1N00000FBnrC']))
{
    http_response_code(401);
    return;
}

$url ='https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8';
$ch = curl_init($url); //var global

Hasta el momento todo OK! Gracias

Comment: Hoy me volvió a llegar otro vacío
¿Estaré haciendo algo mal?


Saludos

Comment: Tambien debes poner una validacion en la url https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8 hize una prueba y se puede ingresar directamente.